# Define a map $t:\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R \times\mathbb R$ by $t(a,b) = (a+b,a-b)$. Prove that $t$ is onto.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

What I think is that this can be onto if we let $a$ and $b$ equal to zero.

Answer (score 2):

"onto" means: to each $(u,v) \in \mathbb R^2$ there is $(a,b) \in \mathbb R^2$ such that

$t(a,b)=(u,v)$. Hence you have to show: for each $(u,v) \in \mathbb R^2$ the system of equations

$a+b=u$

$a-b=v$

has a solution $(a,b)$

Answer (score 1):

Take $(x,y)\in\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$. You have to prove that there is $(a,b)\in\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ such that $t(a,b)=(x,y)$. In other words, you have to prove that the following linear system (in variables $a$ and $b$) has solution.
$$\left\{\begin{align}
a+b=x\\
a-b=y
\end{align}\right.$$
This systems has indeed a unique solution given by
$$a=\frac{x+y}{2},\quad b=\frac{x-y}{2}.$$
So, the function is onto and one-to-one.